# What is the benefit of making sub theme in drupal?

Tags: theming

I have created a sub-theme of a theme in Drupal 7. I have done all changes to create this and it is working fine. But I am confused what actually it is for, what are the benefits of making this? 
I know the differences between base theme and sub-theme but I need more information why we create sub-theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the benefits of using sub-theme:

1. You don't need to build your theme from the scratch. You can just use your parent theme styles and its templates. [Drupal bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) is a best example.
2. If a new version of your parent theme arrives, you can just replace it  with your parent theme since no changes were done in that.
3. To override any templates, you can just copy your parent theme template in your sub theme and start modifying.

Answer (score 1):

For instance. You override only files you need to and you have in your sub-theme directory only these files, not all. You can update parent-theme and not overriding your customizations.